# Can NetworkX actually handle None weights as hidden edges in dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: python, networkx, dijkstra

Based on the sparse and opaque documentation of NetworkX, when calculating shortest paths, I've tried assigning weights using function to limit traversals to specific modes of travel.  This weight function assigns the proper weight if the edge is among the traversable types, and `None` if the edge is any other type.

According to the documentation, using a `None` weight makes the edges hidden, so the traversal will ignore them.  But I'm having weird problems when trying to do this.  Specifically, although a path exists using the specified edge weight (and `has_path` confirms this) when I run `single_source_dijkstra` with these weights, it fails to find the path.

So, for both my integrated multimodal network and for my isolated road network, the code

```
nx.has_path(fullNetwork,orig,dest)
nx.has_path(roadNetwork,orig,dest)
```

returns `True`.  Then running it unweighted using

```
roadTime,roadPath = nx.single_source_dijkstra(roadNetwork, source=orig, target=dest)
```

returns a proper time and path, and furthermore

```
roadTime,roadPath = nx.single_source_dijkstra(roadNetwork, source=orig, target=dest, weight='walkTime')
```

also returns a time and path.  This is all as it should be.

I've confirmed that every road edge has a positive float value for 'walkTime', but some other modes of transportation do not.  So I wanted to use the following weight function to run shortest paths that uses this 'walkTime' weight and ignores non-road edges:

```
def roadWalkTime(u,v,attr):
    if attr.get('modality','poo') == 'road':
        return attr.get('walkTime',None)
    else:
        return None

roadTime,roadPath = nx.single_source_dijkstra(fullNetwork, source=orig, target=dest, weight=roadWalkTime)
```

but instead I get

```
  File C:\miniforge3\envs\GAT\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\shortest_paths\weighted.py:747 in multi_source_dijkstra
    raise nx.NetworkXNoPath(f"No path to {target}.") from err

NetworkXNoPath: No path to destin_0.
```

I'm doing this with random pairs of origins and destinations, and the result does not depend on any specific nodes...it always happens.  So I thought I was doing something wrong with the weight function call, so I defined a static weight and tried again.

```
for u,v,attr in fullNetwork.edges(data=True):
    coreNetwork[u][v]['roadWalkTime'] = attr['walkTime'] if attr.get('modality','blah')=='road' else None
```

Now, when I try

```
roadTime,roadPath = nx.single_source_dijkstra(fullNetwork, source=orig, target=destinNode, weight='roadWalkTime')
```

I still get that same error, and even if I isolate the road network, and confirm that a path DOES exist, and all edge have positive float weights called 'walkTime', the call

```
roadTime,roadPath = nx.single_source_dijkstra(roadNetwork, source=orig, target=destinNode, weight='roadWalkTime')
```

fails even though

```
roadTime,roadPath = nx.single_source_dijkstra(roadNetwork, source=orig, target=destinNode, weight='walkTime')
```

does not.

So, is there something I'm doing wrong in specifying or using that weight function?  Or, because it even fails when static, is there something wrong with my definition of 'roadWalkTime'?

Comment: In your position, I would debug these issues using manually created test networks instead of using real and hence messy data. Until you can show that these operations fail in clean test networks, I would assume that the data or your assumptions about the data are incorrect (is the edge attribute really `'modality'` and not `'Modality'`, etc?).

Comment: Yes, that's fair.  I've had issues in the past with `np.nan` being stored as a string `NaN` or `None` values being turned into `np.nan` (which will return `True` is asked if type == float), and something like that could be causing this problem.  But also, I can't find a single example of using a non-lambda external function for weights, so I want to confirm that I did that correctly.

Comment: I think the function is fine. It closely mirrors their own implementation [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py#L41).

Comment: Looking at the git commit messages, you may want to install the current version from source though as the last commit message states: "FIX: MultiDiGraphs keys got lost in weighted shortest paths (#6963)". This may explain your issues...

Comment: Also, rewriting your function as a lambda expression should just be: `lambda u, v, attr: attr.get('walkTIme', None) if attr.get('modality', '') == 'road' else None`